# How can i find the location of installed software in linux?

Tags: linux

Is there any command that I can use in the console to know the location of installed software in linux?

i have copied a xyz.bin from windows machine to linuxdesktop and installed it.

more over can you please tell me how to uninstall a software which is installed in linux

Thanks in advance

Comment: This Q is related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If it wasn't installed via the package manager, it is normally hard to uninstall.

Comment: You might be able to use the find command to search for it. Have a look at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19369/how-to-find-the-installation-path-for-a-software-under-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a package is installed/uninstalled on Linux depends on either the specific Linux distribution AND the specific package.

Since you have used a .bin file for installation, it is likely that you have an uninstall command specific for your program in the path.

If you provide more information about the package and the Linux distribution, we can give more help.

Comment: red Hat enterprise linux server release 6.5(Santiago)

Answer (score 18):

You may want to use

```
which [your_app_name]
```

to find the path where the binary is linked to.

Other application specific files may reside in

```
~/.[your_app_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the distribution you're using. Supposing you are using a debian\ubuntu distribution, you can uninstall it by the apt command, using 
    sudo apt-get remove software_name
    sudo apt-get purge software_name

Of course you need to have root privileges.

The softwares are usually installed in bin folders, in /usr/bin, /home/user/bin and many other places, a nice starting point could be the find command to find the executable name, but it's usually not a single folder. The software could have components and dependencies in lib,bin and other folders.